# Flex box not working well in RTL direction layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, direction

Firefox is working, but the latest Chrome version is not!

The example will hide the third (red) column and this is the purpose, but when you try to resize the output window width, the third (red) column will be shown, this's just an RTL problem. if you change the layout to ltr, everything will be nice

this's the example: http://jsbin.com/gobisimiyo/edit?output

Any ideas?!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You can hardly use `flex: none` on the columns, and pretend that's actually still a flexbox layout ...

Comment: @CBroe This's not working, can you edit the example and give me the new link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This's a *Chrome* bug, but i fix it by adding `overflow-x: hidden` to to the flex container element

**Note:** this bug is just happened in a `nowrap` **flex-wrap** property.

**Fixed example:** http://jsbin.com/gibiwi/edit?output

Comment: i'd the same issue and it helped me!